# How to detect your subnet? (with Amazon webservices or others)

Tags: networking, amazon-ec2

I know that Amazon has a web service to detect your IP address and another one to detect your network with CIDR notation.

They can be even used just by calling the page from the browser, with a URL, the response is human readable.

I saw the URLs calls using firebug in elasticfox. However elasticfox doesn't work in firefox 4.

So I would like to know, if anyone knows the two URLs or if anyone knows if and how is possible to make elasticfox work with FF4. I know there also the Amazon console, but seems no firewall support. I had to resort writing my firewall application, but I need to detect the user subnet.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

elasticfox does work with ff4 if you edit a file.

You can edit install.rdf (and maybe ec2gui.rdf) to change the maxVersion to 4.0.*: See here: http://kb.mozillazine.org/Editing_an_add-on_to_change_its_compatibility While you are making changes, you can make a few more to update ElasticFox: Fix background transparency: http://dirty-code.blogspot.com/2011/03/problems-with-elastic-fox-in-ff4.html Add support for new EC2 instance types...

taken from

http://sourceforge.net/projects/elasticfox/develop

Comment: Good shot, thank you! So the .xpi archive is actually in .zip format,
I renamed elasticfox.xpi in elasticfox.xpi.zip, unzipped, changed install.rdf, then went to add ons, choose "Install add on from file..." in the gear menu and it works.
Now for those URLs, here they are:
http://checkip.amazonaws.com/
http://checkip.amazonaws.com/block

Comment: Side note, why is it that Elasticfox is not getting updated? In many respects AWS console is more powerful, but sometimes Elasticfox is handy.

Comment: There are many forks out there from people that have support ff4 and made some ui tweaks.